# jQuery trigger event at specific mouse coordinates

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a semi-transparent header and footer and I need to listen for click and hover events and trigger the same event on a different DOM element at the same mouse location.

The following snippet works great for getting the mouse coordinates, but triggering the same event with `$("#container").trigger(e);` does not have the desired effect.

```
        $("#header, #footer").click(function(e){
          //only intercept click if it did not fall on an a tag
          if(!$(e.target).is("a")){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#container").trigger(e); //does not work
            alert(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY); //works
            return false;
          }
        });
```

Comment: have you attached a `click` handler to the `#container` element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending a lot of time in the jQuery documentation, I came up with this solution that works. @Gaby @brad thanks for the input

```
//listen for clicks and mousemovement in the header/footer
//and pass event through to the content div where applicable
$("#header, #footer").bind("click mousemove", function(e){  
    //only intercept event if it did not fall on an "a" tag 
    //within header/footer
    if(!$(e.target).is("a")){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#container").trigger(e);
        return false;
    }
});

$("#container").bind("click mousemove", function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();  
    //get the coordinates of all "a" decendents of #container  
    $(this).find("a").each(function(){   
        var pos = $(this).offset();  
        var height = $(this).height();
        var width = $(this).width();
        //determine if this event happened
        //within the bounds of this "a" element
        if((e.pageX >= pos.left && e.pageX <= (pos.left + width))
           && (e.pageY >= pos.top && e.pageY <= (pos.top + height))){
            //if event type is mousemove, trigger hover
            if(e.type == "mousemove"){
                $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
                //else, pass trigger on to element as is (click)
            } else {
                window.location = $(this).attr("href");
            } 
        }
    });
    //prevent bubbling
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [api for trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) states that it takes a string as the parameter.  You're passing it the actual [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), something like:

```
$("#container").trigger(e.type);
```

should work.

This is assuming you've already done something like:

```
$("#container").bind('click', function(e){ //do something });
```

ie bound the click event to the #container

Comment: @brad This works, but I lose the e.pageX and e.pageY mouse coordinates, so I do not know where on #container they want to click.

Comment: ah sorry, didn't notice you had that as a requirement...  good question i'll have to think about that.

Comment: @brad, passing an event works just fine (*since v1.3*). Look at the docs at http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ (*2nd constructor*)

Comment: @brad, @Roxtonic it should work as this example proves http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/3F38g/ Are you sure there is a handler on the `#container` ?

Comment: @Gaby Yep there is a handler on #container, but the event is registered for the entire DOM element, not for the specific mouse coordinates. If there is a href link in #container at the mouse coordinates, I want the link to be activated.

Comment: @roxtonic, for this to work, the element that you want to receive the event must be a parent of the element you manually fire the event on. This is how bubbling events work http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html. You would need to use the capturing phase of the event order to do it, but that is not currently supported by jquery (*expected in v1.5*). The way it now works, is you fire an event on something and that bubbles up the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: @roxtonic, i am still not sure if it will even work with capturing events, when the event is manually-made.

Comment: @Gaby thanks for your help. I think I'm going to try a different approach.